# How can I figure out what a text file is compressed with?

Tags: json, text, hex, compression, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to decompress this text file (`ClientSettings.sav`) on my hard drive. The original size of the file is around 28kb, and it's been compressed down to 2kb. I'm unsure what steps to take from here as I'm not too experienced with this, and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

[This is what some of it looks like in a hex editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHdLt.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `78 9c` is the start of a zlib stream. You did not provide any clues in your question or tags as to what programming language you are using, but most have an interface to the zlib library.